# Azure PowerShell automation "no default subscritpion has been designated"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am getting the following error.  I am in fact setting the default subscription name.

> 4/27/2015 10:28:28 AM, Error: Get-AzureVM : No default subscription
>   has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default
>    to  set the default subscription. At test:9 char:9
>   + 
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], ApplicationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzureVMCommand

Here is my code:

```
workflow test
{
     # Initial set up
    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "******"
    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
    Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName 'Beebunny'

    $vmName = "MyMachineName"
    Get-AzureVM -servicename $vmName

    Write-output "All done."
}
```

If I try Select-AzureSubscription -Default 'SubscriptionName' it throws an error saying the syntax is invalid.

Edit: I have also tried Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'SubscriptionName' without the Default flag.

Funny thing is that if I run this in AzurePS directly from Windows, it runs just fine.  I am about 95% sure this is an Azure bug but wanted to get a second opinion first.

Comment: Have you tried without `-Default` (just with `-SubscriptionName 'name'`) ?

Answer (score 2):

What version of the Azure module do you have loaded?  Are you using the default module provided by the Automation service? Also, have you imported any other modules to this subscription?

Try creating a clean runbook with the following code, replacing the credential and subscription with the proper names.  Can you get the credential and authenticate successfully?

```
workflow Test-GetVM
{

    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'AdAzureCred'
    if(!$Cred) {
        Throw "Could not find an Automation Credential Asset named. Make sure you have created one in this Automation Account."
    }

    $Account = Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
    if(!$Account) {
        Throw "Could not authenticate to Azure. Make sure the user name and password are correct."
    }

    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN"
    Get-AzureVM
}
```

UPDATE: Do you have the Resource Manager module loaded to the subscription as well?

Comment: I'm tempted to say "this should be a comment", but there's no way that code is fitting. Can you [edit] to add the cases you're aware of, to cut down on the back and forth of answering intermediary questions?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, I tried running your script in workbook but it throws "Could not authenticate to Azure." every time. Double checked the credentials by printing their username/password in the test pane and that is correct. Any other ideas what could throw this error?

Comment: Did you follow all of the steps in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-configuring/#configuring-authentication-to-azure-resources to make sure the credential you are using is properly set up?    If you are managing ARM resources, you should also take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-sec-configure-azure-runas-account/.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution was execute Add-AzureAccount, do the login process requested and once done all was working.

Comment: how can you do that in powershell script? you can't pop up add-azureaccount box there. I am trying to set this up for TFS build.

Comment: Try with the PowerShell ISE.